# How to immediately invoke jquery upon clicking remote link in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm making a an ajax voting link that gets its html class attribute changed upon clicking it.

Currently, it works, but I have to reload the page to see the changes. How can I get this to visually change immediately upon clicking?

I have a remote link, the following jquery, and a `render @votable` at the end of the action `vote_socionics`

My suspicion is that the issue is that my jquery isn't set up to continually detect changes (acting as "live"), or it's with my render call in the controller.

Thanks in advance.

**coffeescript file in assets folder** http://js2coffee.org/

```
windowReady = ->
  jQuery -> 
    $voteLinks = $('.vote-button a')

    $voteLinks.each (i, current) ->
      if $(current).data('voted') == true
        $(current).addClass('voted')

    $voteLinks.on "ajax:success", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
      alert('a')   #...this doesn't execute
      $voteLinks.removeClass('voted')
      $voteLinks.each (i, current)->
        if $(current).data('voted') == false
          $(current).addClass('voted')

$(window).load(windowReady);
$(window).on('page:load', windowReady);
```

---

**html** http://www.haml-converter.com/

```
.vote-button
  = link_to send("vote_socionics_#{votable_name}_path", votable, vote_type: "#{s.type_two_im_raw}"), 
    method: :post, remote: true, 
    data: { voted: @voted_statuses[i] }, 
    id: "vote-#{s.type_two _im_raw}" do end


#...Ignore most of the details here, just the `dat-*` attribute is important. 
#...The desired visual changes successfully happen when I refresh the page, so there is no issues here.
#...The above indented for visual clarity. (My actual code has no issues with haml indentation
```

**concern included in controller**

```
module SocionicsVotesConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  inclued do

    def vote_socionics
      #...some voting logic code.

      render @votable   #... <--is this the issue?
    end   

  end    
end

private
  def set_votable
    votable_constant = controller_name.singularize.camelize.constantize
    @votable = votable_constant.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**controller**

```
class CharactersController < ApplicationController
  include SocionicsVotesConcern

  before_action :set_character

  def show

  end
end

private
  def character_params
    #...stuff
  end

  def set_character
    @character = Character.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I have to reload the page to see the changes

--

**Ajax**

What you're asking is how to get Ajax to work

The answer is relatively simple *if* you understand how Ajax works. I think you do, but for clarity, let me give you a clearer definition:

[image]

Ajax is essentially a way to initiate a "pseudo" browser request. Typically, when you send a request to a server, it will go through the HTTP protocol (using certain headers that I'm not sure about right now). Whilst Ajax still uses the HTTP protocol, it sends an [XHR request (XML Http Request)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)

XHR (or ["ajax" - Asynrhconous Javascript and XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) - as it's become known) is a javascript implementation on sending requests "out of scope" to your server. I mention "out of scope", because the typical HTTP request scope is `request -> server -> response`; Ajax's flow is built *on top* of this - allowing you to send requests to the server *after* an initial response has been rendered

**Simply**, Ajax is a "pseudo browser", which can send extra requests to your server. As it's handled with JS, you can then process the response, changing the body of your view as a result

--

**Response**

Ajax always "hears" a response from the server, even if it's just a collection of headers.

The difference is if you want to *use* the response to manipulate the DOM (your view) in some way, you'll be able to do it with *if* you're able to capture the response from the server with JS

There are two ways to do this:

> - "Standard" JQuery (using [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))
> - "Rails [UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax)" (using the Rails response hooks)

Looks like you know what's going on, so I'll detail how I would look at the problem for you now:

---

**Fix**

Your code looks good to me!!

I think the problem is that you're not delegating the `ajax:success` call properly:

```
windowReady = ->
  $voteLinks = $('.vote-button a')

  $voteLinks.each (i, current) ->
    if $(current).data('voted') == true
      $(current).addClass('voted')

  $(document).on "ajax:success", ".vote-button a", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
    alert('a')   #...this doesn't execute
    $voteLinks.removeClass('voted')
    $voteLinks.each (i, current)->
      if $(current).data('voted') == false
        $(current).addClass('voted')

$(document).on('page:load ready', windowReady)
```

I changed the `$voteLinks.on` to be delegated from `$(document)`.

If your `alert` isn't firing, it generally means that JS is not "binding" to the element correctly. If this is the case, you'll typically be best served by delegating from the `$(document)` object, which is always going to be present in your view (Turbolinks problems)

Please try this & let me know what happens!

Comment: Rich Peck to the rescue again. Thanks so much! I'll let you know in a bit

Comment: I have to say, learning how ajax works and the concrete details of implementing it have been very confusing to learn. I've read many resources, but information is rather scattered, rather than neatly packaged. Answers from the SO community have been seriously amazing for education. I think I grasp the concepts of ajax well, but am not sure about translating those concepts into practice within code.

Comment: Changing the last line's call to `document` rather than `window` breaks the functionality, not even applying the classes when it should. Getting rid of the `jQuery ->` didn't make things better.

Comment: I actually have a functioning script for comments. https://gist.github.com/ahnbizcad/555e5aa2f3afb0d16486
It uses `jQuery ($) ->` and `$(window).load(windowReady)` without any problems.

You'll see my current code in the 2nd file of the gist

Comment: Also, I believe `$(document).on ".vote-button a", "ajax:success", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->`

should be `$(document).on "ajax:success", ".vote-button a", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->` That doesn't solve it either.

Comment: Let's chat about this

Comment: If I keep writing more comments like this, hopefully "let's chat about this" link will appear ;)

Comment: Testing another comment. If this doesn't do it, I'll just make a chatroom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59448/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-gwho).